# How to split a county layer, but keep all surrounding counties per layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson

I have a shapefile of all US counties.
I need to split the shapefile by county, and save in a county file in the file type GeoJSON. This makes about 3k files.
That's easy.

The hard part is that for each county shapefile, I also need the surrounding counties in the shapefile.

For example, the McHenry County shapefile will have the polygon representing McHenry County, but also all the touching counties (i.e. Lake, Boone, deKalb....etc.).  The Lake County shapefile would have the touching counties (i.e. Mchenry, etc..)

The resulting shapefiles will then be exported out has GeoJSONs.

How do I capture the "surrounding counties" along with the target county, and save off as GeoJSON?

Comment: There are only 3143 counties in the US (including DC).  Where are you getting 70 thousand files?

Comment: you are right.  3143....I was looking at the layer for geotract.